# JavaScript variable related

Tags: javascript, variables

I've got this function that defines a random color set.

My issue is defining the variable (`var target`) to select the new color set from the `kuler` object.

```
kuler: {
    set0:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set1:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set2:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set3:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set4:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set5:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set6:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9']
},
setNewColourSet: function () {
    rn=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        var target = "project.kuler.set"+rn+"["+i+"]";
        $('.kuler'+i).css('background-color',target);
        /* works *///  $('.kuler'+i).css('background-color',project.kuler.set4[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `kuler` is a property of a much larger object.

Comment: correct, i left out the rest of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In think you were close -- just put the string within the square braces.

`var target = project.kuler['set' + rn][i];`

assuming `rn` is the number appended to `'set'`, and `kuler` is itself in an object literal called `project`.

Note the first brace (`kuler['set'+rn]`) is property access on the object literal `kuler`, and the second brace (`[i]`)is array index access on an array....

Comment: yeah, i need to wait 2mins before it will let me answer. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
kuler: {
    set0:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set1:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set2:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set3:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set4:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
    set5:['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
    set6:['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9']
},
setNewColourSet: function () {
    var rn = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    $('.kuler'+i).css('background-color', this.kuler['set'+i][rn]);
    }
}
```

here you go

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have an object with **numbered names** like this, why not just have a list?

```
kuler: [
  ['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
  ['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
  ['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
  ['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
  ['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9'],
  ['#0F2440','#2C3F59','#518C8C','#94BEAC','#D9CAAD'],
  ['#499E8D','#85CC9F','#A4DEAB','#C8E8C7','#FFF6C9']
],

setNewColourSet: function () {
  rn=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
  for (i=0; i<4; i++){        
    $('.kuler'+i).css('background-color',kuler[rn][i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. unsure why i didn't do this in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes we over-engineer our solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

var target = "project.kuler.set"+rn+"["+i+"]";

You are assigning a string to a target.

I suppose project is an object and the kuler is a part of it so try with removing quotes;